# How to get FTP directory listings with wininet?

Tags: c++, wininet

h and I would like to get the files of a directory using C++ winapi and a listbox to show contents.
This is the function im using currently: FtpGetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: It will not let me fix it, is there aa moderation for editing posts?

Comment: What code are you using? And what doesn't work?

Comment: Have you looked at/tried Microsoft's [ftptree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728902.aspx) sample? It uses the MFC wrappers around WinInet, but assuming it does what you want, "Liberating" it from MFC shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Comment: FtpFindFirstFile/InternetFindNextFile?